# Two-way lookup with VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, match, vlookup

I am trying to create a two-way lookup in Excel in column **D** based on the references below:

- Cell A1 to match the values in column I
- Cell C5 to match the values in row 5

I used the formula: ***=VLOOKUP(A1,I6:P213,MATCH(C5,I5:P5,0),0)*** but I get an error.
It might be due to the MATCH function because the values from Column C are from a vlookup (General format). If I replace them by a number 3, it gives me the value in the third row.

FYI:
-Column E is just multiplying A by D.

Here is the top of my table:
[image]

Comment: It looks like you have text-that-looks-like-numbers in column C.

Comment: Yes, it comes from a vlookup. I found a quick fix for it by adding a column next to it and multiplying the value by 1 to make it a number.

Answer (score 0):

I found a quick fix for it in the meantime by adding a column after C and multiplying the text value In column C by 1 to obtain a number.

The formula was also amended to:
***=VLOOKUP($A$1,$J$6:$Q$213,MATCH(D5,$J$5:$Q$5,0),0)***